# Calculate the values of dependent variable using multivariate linear regression with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement `multivariate linear regression` using `numpy`. There are several questions in this forum regarding that but seems to answer my question. I have the following independent variables `(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)` and dependent variable `Y`. I want to predict the values of `Y'`.

```
X1    X2   X3   X4    Y    Y'
1     0     1    0    1    ? // ? -> referring this value as y'1
0     0     1    1    0    ? // ? -> referring this value as y'2
0     1     0    1    0    ? // ? -> referring this value as y'3
0     0     0    1    1    ? // ? -> referring this value as y'4
1     0     1    1    0    ? // ? -> referring this value as y'5
```

So, I am using numpy as:

```
>>> X1 = np.array([1,0,0,0,1])
>>> X2 = np.array([0,0,1,0,0])
>>> X3 = np.array([1,1,0,0,1])
>>> X4 = np.array([0,1,1,1,1])
>>> Y = np.array([1,0,0,1,0])
>>> x = np.array([X1,X2,X3,X4], np.int32)
>>> n = np.max(x.shape)   
>>> X = np.vstack([np.ones(n), x]).T
>>> print np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y)[0]
 [  2.00000000e+00  -2.22044605e-16  -1.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e+00]
```

So, I have the equation `y = a + b1.x1 +b2.x2 + b3.x3 + b4.x4` . From above, I have got the values of `a,b1,b2,b3,b4`.

So,how do I calculate the values of `Y'` which are `y'1`, `y'2`,`y'3`, `y'4`,`y'5` from the above coefficient values?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. What does `Y'` represent? If you don't know its values *anywhere*, then you will have a hard time predicting ... On a side note: there exist implementations for this in `sklearn` and `statsmodels`. Are you coding this for comprehension or real life use? (In the latter case, use what is already coded.)

Answer (score 0):

The point of OLS is to fit parameters based on data you have and use that to predict a new Y.  Try ...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,1], [0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,1]])
>>> Y = np.array([1,0,0,1,0]).reshape((5,1))
>>> b = np.linalg.inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)
>>> b
out [1]: array([[0.666], [-0.333], [-0.333], [0.333]])
```

Then use this to predict a new Y given 4 new X's.  Also, if your Y's are binary (all zeros and ones), you should look at using Logistic Regression.